# Try to check a checkbox based on values in a table

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to use jQuery to loop over rows in a table, if the first td has a certain value then look for a checkbox on that row and check it.

```
$('#table1').find('tr').each(function(){
    var prod = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    if(prod == 'string value'){
        $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true); 
    alert(prod);
    }
});
```

But this does not work. The alert shows that the text matches that in the first cell, but it does not tick the radio button in the last cell.
Not sure what i am doing wrong with this

I use a similar piece of code to select the checkbox based on clicking the row, which works fine.

```
$('#table1').find('tr').click( function(){
  var row = $(this).find('td:first').text();
  $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);    
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Off topic: `$('#table1 tr')` would be adequate here.

Comment: Are they checkboxes or radio buttons? You seem to be mixing the two terms.

Comment: This seems to work fine [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3x71qbs3/)

Comment: provide html sample. if using `radio` could be a problem trying to set more than one radio in a group as checked. Also could have white space issues in `text()`

Comment: You probably know this but, you should consider using a class on the tr instead of checking the text value in the td if possible...

Comment: Please provide a working example of this with as little code as possible. I tried to recreate your scenario and here it seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hzo2y9o1/3/